# Database hosted in Azure virtual machine is the same as if hosted on normal remote hosts?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I would like to host a firebird database in an Azure virtual machine.
Normally, I would indicate in a program a connection like this:

```
hostname:databasename
```

....to connect to remote host. In azure, you cannot do that.

I would need to connect with something like:

```
 ?.cloudapp.net:someport:databasename
```

The client would be talking to `?.cloudapp.net` thinking that `someport` is the port to communicate with the database server.

So it seems I would need a proxy to login-connect to windows azure cloud resources and the client would then use the proxy to talk with the database server. This looks like a hassle - are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of your Cloud architecture in Azure, but assuming you have one VM with your DB installed you should be able to open up a a public endpoint (via the portal manage.windowsazure.com for your Cloud Service) and connect to that via it's public IP address & the port).

Windows Azure does have more advanced features that allows you to connect to specific VM's within a Cloud Service via Port Forwarding.

Michael Washam has a great blog post on this 'Windows Azure Virtual Machines':
http://michaelwasham.com/2012/06/08/understanding-windows-azure-virtual-machines/

> The architecture of cloud services makes endpoint configuration
>   interesting. Since each cloud service has a single public IP address
>   but multiple virtual machines can reside in it how do you address
>   individual servers directly in a non-load balanced fashion?
>
> Port forwarding allows you to configure an endpoint on a specific VM
>   listening on any of the ephemeral ports that will then be forwarded to
>   the correct internal port.